# Qt6 QClipboard doesn't put anything in the clipboard (Linux)

Tags: qt6, qclipboard

I've been trying to get a simple app to work on Linux using QClipboard to copy some information to the system clipboard.  The code that does the copy to clipboard is very simple:

```cpp
        qDebug() << "Copying to clipboard:" << result;
        QClipboard *clipboard = QGuiApplication::clipboard();
        qDebug() << "Existing content (to be overwritten):" << clipboard->text(QClipboard::Clipboard);
        clipboard->setText(result, QClipboard::Clipboard);
        qDebug() << "Clipboard contents:" << clipboard->text(QClipboard::Clipboard);
```

When it runs, the printed clipboard contents before `setText` show the existing contents of the clipboard and the printed clipboard contents after `setText` show the text that should have been copied to the clipboard. All looks okay.  However, nothing is in the clipboard.  If I run the same thing again, the existing clipboard contents is shown as empty:

```
$ ./output/linux/digraph # Then type "VE" and click "Copy to Clipboard"
Copying to clipboard: "Version: v1.0.3-15-4700916fe26d\nCompiled 8th January 2023"
Existing content (to be overwritten): "Manually copied to clipboard"
Clipboard contents: "Version: v1.0.3-15-4700916fe26d\nCompiled 8th January 2023"

# But clipboard is empty!

$ ./output/linux/digraph # Then type "VE" and click "Copy to Clipboard"
Copying to clipboard: "Version: v1.0.3-15-4700916fe26d\nCompiled 8th January 2023"
Existing content (to be overwritten): ""
Clipboard contents: "Version: v1.0.3-15-4700916fe26d\nCompiled 8th January 2023"

# Clipboard still empty!

$ ./output/linux/digraph # Then type "VE" and click "Copy to Clipboard"
Copying to clipboard: "Version: v1.0.3-15-4700916fe26d\nCompiled 8th January 2023"
Existing content (to be overwritten): ""
Clipboard contents: "Version: v1.0.3-15-4700916fe26d\nCompiled 8th January 2023"

# Clipboard still empty!
```

Is there something else I need to do to make the written clipboard contents be visible to other applications and to persist after the application quits?

The full source code of the application is here: https://github.com/abudden/digraph ; it works on Windows (but uses [the Windows API to do the copy as I found QClipboard worked but was unreliable](https://github.com/abudden/digraph/blob/master/src/windows_specific.cpp#L53)) and is arguably a bit pointless on Linux with Compose Key type features, but someone asked me if I could make it work on Linux, so I'm trying.

Comment: X11 has the concept of both a 'global clipboard' and a 'selection clipboard', so it might depend on how you are pasting the data afterwards. Please see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qclipboard.html#notes-for-x11-users for more details.

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/a/67212576/4928207 mentions that adding a slight delay after setting the clipboard might help in reliably getting the data on the clipboard in linux.

Comment: Thanks @MarkJansen. I've checked both clipboards (and the two clipboards is the reason that the code above specifies which clipboard to use). I'll try the delay, but given that the main code repeats the copies 8 times with a 5 ms delay between each copy, I'd be surprised if it helps. What I find most weird is that reading from the clipboard with Qt gives the correct answer, but other apps can't see it.

Comment: Looking again at the SO link, the delay is only 1 ms and I'm already adding a lot more than that: https://github.com/abudden/digraph/blob/89f6d0cf3b35640727126b5670a8dca26e608be1/src/digraph.cpp#L241

Comment: Do you have a message loop in the thread that copies the data to the clipboard? Did you try running another Qt application to check if the data is available on the clipboard?

Comment: I haven't tried a **different** Qt application (but I will).  I've tried running the same Qt application again (it reads from the clipboard and writes the output to the debug console before trying to change anything) and it thinks the clipboard is empty.  I'd be surprised if a different Qt application produces a different result, but I'll check.

I don't really understand what you mean by "a message loop in the thread that copies the data".  There's only one thread and it's not doing very much: waiting for characters to be typed in and when the second character is entered, it does the copy.

Comment: The qt link states: *Lastly, the X11 clipboard is event driven, i.e. the clipboard will not function properly if the event loop is not running.*

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise "event loop" and "message loop" are the same thing.  I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't be running; the keyboard event has just fired (when the user typed the digraph) causing the code to be run that triggers the copy to clipboard.  Similarly, there's a copy to clipboard button that runs the code and also does nothing - presumably an event linked the button to the code (via a signal & slot).  Given that an event has triggered the copy, I can only assume that (what I think of as) the event loop is running.  Of course, there might be a subtlety I'm missing.